# rm -f command results in an error in React.js

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I am following the tic-tac-toe game to learn React.js. After creating the app when I run this command `rm -f src/*` it gives the following error:

```
    C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-app>rm -f src/*
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Note: I have installed node.js 8.11.3 version. What can I try next?

Comment: rm is a Unix command and you seem to be using Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using windows, try this -

```
rd /s /q "src/*"
```